# Problema con Ajax y Html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Muy buenas,
Estoy comenzando con todas estas tecnologías, HTML AJAX PHP JQUERY etc
Perdonar por si veis mucha "basura" a penas llevo 2 semanas con todo esto.

Estas son mis dos páginas, **logeo.php**
la cual se encarga de comprobar que existe o no un usuario para posteriormente logearse y mi página **index.php** donde creo que se encuentra el problema.
Adjunto código.

```
    <?php

include "conectarse.php";

//Obtener los datos de la pag web.
$usuario = $_POST['botonUser'];
$pass1 = $_POST['botonPass'];

//Procedo a conectarme a la Base de Datos
$link = conectarse($baseDatos);

$query_select = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND pass = '$pass1';";

$registro = $link->query($query_select);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registro))
    {    
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['nom'] = $row['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['apellido'] = $row['apellido'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['tiempo'] = strftime("Hoy es %A y son las %H:%M");

    echo 'Si';

    }
    else {
        session_start();

        echo "No";
        $_SESSION['nom'] = "Anonimo";
    }

$link->close();

?>
```

**index.php**, mi página principal.
Mi idea en esta página es la siguiente, dependiendo de si el logeo ha sido correcto ( devuelve **Si**  logeo.php ) o erroneo ( devuelvo **No** logeo.php ) este método lo filtra y modifica mi página inicial cambiando su html, en este caso aparece un iframe que solo pueden ver los usuarios que están logeados.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#enviarLogin').click(function() {  

        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "login.php",  
        data: $(formularioLogin).serialize(),
        ajax.done (function())
           success:function(data) 
            {
             /*if (data.toString().trim() == "Si") {
                $("#elementos").css('display' , 'inline');
             }
             else {
              alert ("No he entrado");*/
             }
            }
        });  
    });  
});
```

Aquí viene mi problema, no se por qué motivo, cuando realizo esto y ejecuto con la consola de Chrome paso a paso me muestra el iframe durante X segundos que dura la ejecución, sin embargo al terminar la misma mi página vuelve al estado inicial.
Lo mismo me ocurre si todo lo ejecuto del tirón usando mi propia web, aparece durante unos milisegundos y la pagina vuelve a su estado inicial, no mostrando el iframe que deseaba tras realizar el logeo en mi pag. web.

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay un error con los paréntesis y las llaves, debería ser: `ajax.done (function(){`. Además, no se han comentado bien las llaves del if-else y no coinciden las de apertura y cierre

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar done y success juntas porque prácticamente hacen lo mismo, solo que success ahora es deprecated. Yo lo pondría así:

```
$('#enviarLogin').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: {  $("formRegistro").serialize(); }//aqui no se si debe ir ; (no lo probe)
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        /*if (data.toString().trim() == "Si") {
            $("#elementos").css('display' , 'inline');
        }
        else {
            alert ("No he entrado");
        }*/
    });
});
```

Comment: No, no llevaría ";", además yo sugiero que si su botón es un "submit", el evento click lo va realizar pero igual el del submit, refrescando la página y regresandola a su estado original, cambiarla a un botón, o hacerlo en el evento submit del formulario solventaría el problema.